# MKMapView inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, mkmapview

I have a UITableView with UITableViewCells that contains a MKMapView.

The Problem: if the table cell ever gets selected, then move the map, you see the mapview is all white and you only see the "Legal" label.

Has anyone experienced this before?

[image: screenshot]

Here is the entire code:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 5;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 70;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MKMapView *map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 220, 70)];

    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D logCord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.606, -122.332);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(logCord, span);
    [map setRegion:region animated:NO];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"aaaa"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:map];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced this.

In my case, the map becomes white like this if its tableView or cell has a backgroundColor and its cell has either a gray or blue selection style and the cell is recycled through dequeue.

I think that the map won't turn white like this if

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: I already tried that, can confirm that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Ah, ok what actually was causing the white map in my case was setting self.tableView.backgroundColor in viewWillAppear.

Setting tableView's backgroundColor in viewDidLoad doesn't produce the problem.

The cell's selection style doesn't matter.

Comment: In case this helps anyone, if your using a nib for the UITableViewCell then its possible that the nib has the selectionStyle set to something different than is being set programatically.  The nib may not have loaded when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called (where cell.selectionStyle is programmatically set) and then the selection style is reset to the value in the nib.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this as well.

My map had white background when it was touched after pushing/popping another detail view controller. TableView has no color/background configured yet, everything is default.

```
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

...actually helped.