# MapView on TableViewCell issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, dictionary

I am trying to show a map view in the TableViewCell. I have crated a `Cell` from another view and tried to merge it to the main view. but I have an issue that I can't see the map view. Why I always get an empty map with only pin?

When I run the app

[image: When I run the app]

This is when I touch the cell

[image: This is when I touch the cell]

Comment: Does it work after calling `[cell setNeedsDisplay]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I hope you are to do the achieve the same and I achieved the same by simply adding:

```
[cell addSubview:self.mapView];
```

Cheers!!

Let me know if you need more clarification.

**ADDITION:**

```
[self.mapView setScrollEnabled:FALSE];
```

Comment: Thanks it works. BTW do you know how to make the map not moveable?

Comment: Please see the code added for "make the map not movable", which is marked under ADDITION.

Answer (score 1):

make background color of your cell's view to UIClear color.

Answer (score 0):

It`s because the cell is selected ,and its  , unselect the cell (from code or storyboard/xib) and blue background will dissapear , or just set tableview selectable to false

Comment: My problem is that I can't view the map not the map is selected or not.

Comment: please check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823185/mkmapview-inside-a-uitableviewcell